# ReactJS + MaterialUI: SelectField height change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, material-ui

I'm using React material-ui `SelectField` on my page. I'm not able to adjust the height of the select field. Here is my code snippet:

```
<SelectField
  underlineStyle={{
    display: 'none'
  }}
  style={{
    width: '49%',
    padding: '0 0 5em 5em',
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    margin: '16px 0px 0px 28px',
  }}
  floatingLabelText="Select Stack*"
  value={this.state.stack}
  onChange={this.handleStackChange.bind(this)}
>
  {this.state.dropDownStack}
</SelectField>
```

My UI is looking as below [image]

I need to reduce the height of dropdown box, how can I do it?

Comment: You want to reduce to what? Did you try adding `height`? Could you provide an example of the result you are expecting?

Comment: @Nithyananth It sounds like your need to use bootstrap. I recommend you `react-native-elements`. Works fine for me! :)

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I need to reduce the height of SelectField area. Please refer the image attached with 'Select Stack as placeholder'

Comment: Did you try adding `height` to its style?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca `height` doesnt making any change. I have tried it..

Answer (score 1):

You have to set it using following:

```
<SelectField
    className="custom-selectfield"
    underlineStyle={{
       visibility: 'hidden',
    }}
    floatingLabelStyle={{
        top: '14px',
    }}
    style={{
        border: '1px solid #ccc',
        height: '45px',
    }}
    floatingLabelText="Select Stack*"
    value={this.state.stack}
    onChange={this.handleStackChange.bind(this)}>
 {this.state.dropDownStack}
</SelectField>
```

There is some internal CSS applied in material UI so in order to overwrite it added a custom class to SelectPicker component named *custom-selectfield*

Add following lines in your CSS file

```
.custom-selectfield > div:nth-child(2) {
   margin-top: -6px !important;
}
```